# How to unit test MediatR method that returns ArgumentException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, mediatr

I have an Unit Test case where the method under test is expected to return ArgumentException This specific test snippet was working earlier in ASP.NET (.NET 4.7.2) but with MediatR (ASP.NET Core) I'm facing issues with the construction of the mock of Mediator

Inside the test component in brief I have something like

```
    //initialization
    Mock<IMediator> _mediatorMock;
    
    //constructor 
    _mediatorMock = new Mock<IMediator>();
    
    //user object
    var user = "//some initialization related to user object goes here..."

    //command 
    UpdateUserCommand cmd = //some data
    
    //mocking the method to which the mediator 
    _mediatorMock.Setup(m => m.Send(It.IsAny<UpdateUserCommand>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .Returns((UpdateUserCommand command, CancellationToken cancel) => 
   {
    var t = userDefinitionRepository.Create(user);
    return t as Task<Unit>; // <-------- the expected result is ArgumentException and throws InvalidCast and therefore the mediator is not formed leading to NRE
   });
                        
  // injecting the mediator to the controller  
  var controller = new UserDefinitionController(_mediatorMock.Object);

  //Controller method invocation
  var k = await controller.Post(2, cmd);
```

So, now I'm breaking my head which is the correct way to cast or use the Task as an ArgumentException, to verify the method is indeed throwing the expected response

Thanks

Comment: What is the method signature of `userDefinitionRepository.Create(user)`?

Comment: async Task Create(User userInfo)

Comment: Rather than casting `t` as `Task<Unit>`, return `Unit.Task`. However, I personally wouldn't use a repository to mock my data as its running business logic within a test. I don't know what data source your repository is adding to, but if you're using EF for example, I would specifically insert into the in memory context within the test.